# How to make a function call every few seconds in c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, highcharts

I am building a dashboard using highcharts in asp.net. Now, I have the client side where I used Javascript and Ajax. The backend is done using C#. I have been asked to automatically update the data for various banks every 'x' minutes. Now, I need to call a function to do all the backend stuffs in every few minutes. Then the data will be stored in a container such as an Array and send to the Javascript which does all the display and stuffs.

I don't know How can I make the function to repeatedly call itself every few minutes because the data will be updated in the C# code and the new data will be passed to Javascript (which by the way also refreshes every few minutes).

Comment: Consider using websocket instead of continuous polling.

Comment: try setInterval refer --> http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113596/writing-cs-analog-of-settimeout-setinterval-and-clearinterval

Answer (score 0):

Write your JS method/AJAX call inside `setInterval` function and assign some interval.
For example below code will alert "Hello" every 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds):

```
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

Similar way call your C# method (API) from here which will always return the latest set of data.

Comment: :- Thank you for your reply. Since, my code behind is in a for loop, I need to pause the calculation in the for loop for a specific amount of time and resume the calculation again only when the current data is passed to the JS method. How do I go about it?

Comment: ok.don't use for loop and use a static/global variable k as index which will keep track of the sc.transactionstats(country[k], bankid[k]); method. every time this method is called increase k++ and use that index to retrieve value.

Comment: :- Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use `webmethod` to return `json` in c# And use [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function to call `GetGraphData()` function in given time. 
 Sample `javascript` -

```
function GetGraphData() {
    //ajax call here, call c# webmethod using ajax 
    //and decode json string using JSON.parse()

    // call this function again in 1000ms
    setInterval(GetGraphData, 1000);
}

//add Get graph data in page load 
$(function () {
    //first call
    GetGraphData();
});
```

Sample `WebMethod` -

```
[WebMethod]
public static string calctranscs()
{
    string strJson="";

    //here create json string with your logic

    retutn strJson;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The page load event would call the function only once. You need to create a WebMethod in C#.

```
[WebMethod]
public void calctranscs() {
     for (int i = 1; i < bankid.Length; i++) {
         sc.transactionstats(country[i], bankid[i]);
         merchant_name = sc.MerchantName;
         success_transcs = sc.noofsuccessfultranscs;
         failed_transcs = sc.nooffailedtranscs;
         service_transcs = sc.nooffailedservicetranscs;
         count++;
    }
}
```

Now you call this function from JavaScript (or jQuery preferably).

```
function CallCalctranscs() {     
         $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: '<youraspxpage>.aspx/calctranscs',
         data: "",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (msg) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("failure");
        }
    });
}
```

Call the above function repeatedly.

```
setInterval(CallCalctranscs, 100);
```

Comment: :- Thank you for your help. Though I am a bit confused about one thing. Since, the calctranscs is having a for loop which calls the actual method which does the calculation. I need to be able to send the data in such a way that the foor loop calculation proceeds to the next index only when the previous data is sent to the JS. How do I go about that?

Comment: For that you need to read the response of the AJAX then increment the count in for loop on a successful response (the AJAX function above already has success/failure properties). Also, I would like to suggest you a better approach using ASP.Net SignalR https://www.asp.net/signalr.

Comment: :- Thank you very much.

Comment: :- Just to be clear. How do I fetch the Ajax response back to my aspx.cs class? Do I send the status back to the server and get the result from the server to my cs  class?

Comment: With every AJAX call, the for loop in the C# code would reset. It will be a fresh call for each successful call. With this, you are getting the success/failure response for every calls that is getting triggered from setInterval(). Since your calctranscs() function in C# is void you won't get any data. But anyways, the success and failure blocks as you can see will get hit every time.